# Knative security - unable to create a secure TLS connection using gRPC

Tags: go, kubernetes, grpc, istio, knative

I need a secure connection to Knative.

Tried a milion, and on the top of my head - the following scenario:

```
WORKED:
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------|
| 1. curl -H "Host:  my-servivce.default.mydomin.com" http(s)://mydomain.com | knative-ingress-gateway(tls with cert.pem) |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------|
| 2. unsecure gRPC port:80                                                   | knative                                    |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------|

NOT WORKING:
|-----------------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 3. unsecure gRPC port:443   | knative-ingress-gateway(tls PASSTHROUGH)                                                       |
|-----------------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 4.     --//--               | knative-ingress-gateway(tls with cert.pem) using same working certificate as for 1. (curl)     |
|-----------------------------|--------------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------|
| 5. secure gRPC(cert from 4.)| knative-ingress-gateway(tls PASSTHROUGH)   | gRPC secure server OpenSSL mydomain.com           |
|-----------------------------|--------------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------|    
| 6. OpenSSL secure gRPC      | knative-ingress-gateway(tls PASSTHROUGH)   | gRPC secure server OpenSSL mydomain.com           |
|-----------------------------|--------------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------|
| 7.     --//--               | knative-ingress-gateway(tls PASSTHROUGH)   | gRPC secure server OpenSSL internall host domain  |
|--------------------------   |--------------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------|
```

If you have got anything working with TLS or http(s), or know one who has, I would very much like to know?

Thanks in advance

Comment: doesn't work according to [using-a-tls-cert](https://github.com/knative/docs/blob/master/docs/serving/using-a-tls-cert.md)?

Comment: How do you conclude - Is it something with autoTLS?

Comment: Seems so: [issues/4133](https://github.com/knative/serving/issues/4133)

Comment: Hmm interesting, thanks

Comment: Though, I do have a web server working with https